# Jenkins can't connect to window server - not enough permissions

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I've just installed at local a Jenkins server in order to execute some tests using Selenium Webdriver.

When I execute the tests, the initial steps are executing well (maven calls, access to repo,...) but when the first selenium step have to be executed, I get this error:

```
(java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.)
```

What permissions are refered?

I'm executing from my main user in my computer in a MacOSX.
I've looked information in jenkins site and google, but I can get anything.

Answer (score 10):

Add JVM options `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

On the instance I use, the "JVM Options" field is only visible from the "Advanced..." button under the Launch Method sub-heading.

Comment: On the instance I use, the "JVM Options" field is only visible from the "Advanced..." button under the Launch Method sub-heading.

Comment: Added the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a different JDK to your box and using that for your build?  I had a similar issue with a Jenkins build job on my mac and was able to correct it:
 [Jenkins build failed on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619829/jenkins-build-failed-on-osx/22470528#22470528)