# Jenkins build failed on OSX

Tags: maven-2, jenkins

I am trying to build my project using Jenkins to deploy the artifacts to the nexus. I have a Jenkins setup on my macOSX. 
below is the error, I am getting:

Parsing POMs

> [maventest] $
>   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.3.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/share/maven
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.26.jar
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.3.jar
>   59985

<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started

channel stopped

> ERROR: Failed to parse POMs java.io.IOException: Remote call on
>   Channel to Maven
>   [/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java,
>   -Xmx512m, -XX:MaxPermSize=128m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -cp, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.3.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar,
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main, /usr/share/maven,
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.26.jar,
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.3.jar,
>   59985] failed     at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:727)   at
>   hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:156)    at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:770)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1593)  at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:491)    at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247) Caused by:
>   java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough
>   permissions.  at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1724)     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)    at
>   sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1605)     at
>   java.awt.Toolkit.(Toolkit.java:1627)  at
>   java.awt.Color.(Color.java:263)   at
>   hudson.util.ColorPalette.(ColorPalette.java:39)   at
>   hudson.model.BallColor.(BallColor.java:56)    at
>   hudson.model.Result.(Result.java:51)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor41.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:929)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1759)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
>     at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:979)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
>     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:182)    at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:98)  at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)   at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) Finished: FAILURE

I already tried the below solution but it didn't work:
http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/JIRA-Created-HUDSON-5584-java-io-IOException-Remote-call-on-Channel-to-Maven-td1475049.html

**Configurations I have:**

MAVEN_OPTS:`-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djava.awt.headless=true`

output of ps -ef | grep java: `/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war`

build command:`clean deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=central::default::http://<user>:<pwd>@<host>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public/`

Answer (score 2):

The solution I used was to apply Java 7.  What you want to do is add 1.7 to Jenkins. Following these steps I was able to successfully build my project:

1. Go to the Oracle Java page and downloaded the 1.7_51 jdk for Mac.
2. Opened the dmg and ran the executable.
3. On the Mac, this installs the JDK to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/
4. In Jenkins, go to 'Manage Jenkins' > 'Configure System'
5. Under the JDK heading, click the button that says JDK Installations
6. Under Name type 'JDK 1.7.0_51'
7. For JAVA_HOME type '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/'
8. Select Save
9. Go to your project and select Configure
10. You should now have a JDK drop down near the top of the page.
11. Select the JDK you just configured under 'Manage Jenkins'
12. Run the build

After doing this, my build successfully ran without the 'Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions error.'

Answer (score 0):

This line looks curious:

```
hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247) Caused by: java.lang.InternalError:
Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions. at java.lang.ClassLoader
$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
```

I would start with a simpler project, and then add complexity from that point, for the reason of just testing to make sure your basic assumptions are correct.

You might need to set the JVM property :  `-Djava.awt.headless=true`  .   By doing that you will disable the (most likely unnecessary) gui libraries that are trying to load.

Comment: Thanks, any other idea about it... Is someone has experienced this error before ???

Comment: Ahh. I think I might know what this is.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I am still waiting for the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks! I already tried -Djava.awt.headless=true, as mentioned in my first post. But still it is giving me the same error.