# "InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions" when doing loadLibrary

Tags: java, awt

I am getting an InternalError when trying to load the *awt* library. I followed other SO questions, like this one: [Jenkins can't connect to window server - not enough permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519884/jenkins-cant-connect-to-window-server-not-enough-permissions) in order to get around the problem by setting a system property.  I do not believe that this question is a duplicate of the question that I link to since the suggestion there did not work.

How do I avoid getting the InternalError?

```
[13:16] /tmp
$ cat Foo.java
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("awt");
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
[13:16] /tmp
$ javac Foo.java
[13:16] /tmp
$ java -Djava.awt.headless=false Foo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1833)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1730)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:811)
    at Foo.main(Foo.java:3)
[13:16] /tmp
$ java -Djava.awt.headless=true Foo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1833)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1730)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:811)
    at Foo.main(Foo.java:3)
[13:16] /tmp
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Note that I am trying this simple program in order to work on a larger problem that we are having.  So, running this program is a first step.

---

**EDIT**: This appears to be a Java 6 problem. When I move to a Java 7 JDK, I can properly run this program without using any custom system properties.

Comment: try adding `-Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.HToolkit` as well. Looks like you are on a Mac, and I saw somewhere that its flaky with headless.

Comment: Hmmm...that didn't work either.